# Vue.js return data from axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, v-for

```
<template>
  <div class="comment">
    <div v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
      {{ getUser(comment.student_idx) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import server from '@/models/server'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: server,
      comments: {}
    }
  },
  props: ['idx'],
  created() {
    axios.get(`${this.url}/bamboo/reply?post=${this.idx}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.status === 200) {
        this.comments = response.data.data.replies
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getUser (idx) {
      axios.get(`${this.url}/member/student/${idx}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
          return response.data.data.member.name
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I would like to load the comments at `created` and print them out using v-for.
In v-for, I would like to load the `member.name` from each comment

But `{{ getUser(comment.student_idx) }}` is undefined.
I don't know how to return data from axios
Help me please!!

Comment: Vue templates only render actual data, not promises. You need to assign your axios response to a `data()` property, like `comments`, and then render that data property.

Comment: please, change the return json format.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should not be async for stable run code. My recomendation is next code:

```
<template>
  <div class="comment">
    <div v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
      {{ comments['user'] }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import server from '@/models/server'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: server,
      comments: []
    }
  },
  props: ['idx'],
  created() {
    axios.get(`${this.url}/bamboo/reply?post=${this.idx}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.status === 200) {
        this.comments = response.data.data.replies;
        if(this.comments)
          for(let comment of this.comments){
            this.getUser(comment, comment.student_idx);
          }
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getUser (comment, idx) {
      axios.get(`${this.url}/member/student/${idx}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
          this.$set(comment, 'user', response.data.data.member.name);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't know how to do it. Thank you very much